# Setting one attribute as PK in 2 tables doesnt work in sql

Tags: sql, postgresql

I am trying to set the same column in 2 tables as a primary key, but it doesn't work. When I run it then `mmm` loses object_id as a PK. What is wrong in my query?

```
CREATE TABLE connection (
  object_id INTEGER REFERENCES mmm (object_id),
  medium_id INTEGER REFERENCES media (medium_id),
  PRIMARY KEY (object_id, medium_id)
);
```

My tables:

```
                                        Table "public.media"
  Column   |          Type           |                         Modifiers                         
-----------+-------------------------+---------------------------------
 medium_id | integer                 | not null default nextval('media_medium_id_seq'::regclass)
 medium    | character varying(1500) | 
Indexes:
    "media_pkey" PRIMARY KEY, btree (medium_id)

                  Table "public.mmm"
      Column      |          Type           | Modifiers 
------------------+-------------------------+-----------
 title            | character varying(800)  | 
 artist           | character varying(100)  | 
 mmm_number       | character varying(20)   | 
 object_id        | integer                 | not null
Indexes:
    "mmm_pkey" PRIMARY KEY, btree (object_id)
```

Comment: Creating a table can not alter another table. Did you commit your changes to first 2 tables before you created a third one? (In postgres all queries are transaction and can be rolled back)

Comment: according to your output, `mmm` still has a primary key: `"mmm_pkey" PRIMARY KEY, btree (object_id)`

Comment: it is a table before running that query that creates new table. When I run I loose a PK there